# PHP and the foreach "lower price than?"

Tags: php, xml

I have the following problem I want an lower price than 40 in PHP, but only it don't work.
I have the code here below. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
    $XML = simpleXML_load_file('newtitel.xml');
    echo "<strong>an price</strong><br />";
    $books = $XML->xpath('/newtitel/book');

    foreach($books as $book)
    $books = $XML->xpath("book/price[>.'40']/parent::*"); 
    print_r($books); 
    {
        echo "Titel: {$book->titel}<br />
        ISBN: {$book->isbn}<br />
        Prijs: {$book->price}<br />
        number: {$book->number}<br />";
    }
?>
```

Also I have this maybe it helps..

> **$books= $XML->xpath("book/price[>.'40']/parent::*"); 
>       print_r($books); **

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answer.

Only I get this error.

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid expression in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\help.php on line 18
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\help.php on line 18

And the one price is 59,99 and that is above the 40.

Comment: foreach($books as $book) $books = ... Sure?

Comment: it is so much easier if you *post your complete code* - also your XML structure as a valid sample.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have anything before the opening brace of the `foreach()`:

```
$books = $XML->xpath("book/price[>.'40']/parent::*"); 
foreach($books as $book)
{
    echo "Titel: {$book->titel}<br />
    ISBN: {$book->isbn}<br />
    Prijs: {$book->price}<br />
    number: {$book->number}<br />";
}
```